# Apache: Match static resources

Tags: apache

I would to add `Expires "access"` as a default configuration setting, and to add `Etag:` headers as well, to all **static** resources on a apache webserver with a lot of badly organized content (webserver from my university). That is, I don't want to mess with the headers of resources that are dynamically generated in any way, because I expect them to implement their own caching policies.

So, to make a more general question, is it possible to match requests that map to completely static resources?

Unfortunately, my search-foo didn't lead my to a site answering my question, so I am (assumably) duplicating it here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`<FilesMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive. It's like `<Location>` or `<Directory>` but works on files that have names that match a pattern.

It can't decide if some files content is generated dynamically or not, but it's a start as it doesn't match URLs that aren't files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, we have quite a few python scripts named `.html`.